# perl find and replace from command line. special characters?

Tags: perl, bash, command-line, replace

So, I have looked around for an answer to this, and indeed I have found some, but none seem to work...

I have a folder full of bash scripts that I need to modify.  specifically, I need to replace the line

```
INPUT=/data/scratch02/mpgussert/HAWC-30/${RUN}_reco
```

with

```
INPUT=/data/hawc01/hawcroot/data/hawc/reconstructed/quesadilla/${RUN}
```

I have tried this

```
perl -w -i -p -e "s'INPUT=/data/scratch02/mpgussert/HAWC-30/${RUN}_reco'INPUT=/data/hawc01/hawcroot/data/hawc/reconstructed/quesadilla/${RUN}'g" *.sh
```

which executes without error, but does not find and replace the desired text.  From my understanding, using ' to deliminate the regex should search without special character replacement.  Is that correct?  If so, any ideas why it fails?

I have also tried

```
perl -w -i -p -e "s/INPUT=\/data\/scratch02\/mpgussert\/HAWC-30\/\$\{RUN\}_reco/INPUT=\/data\/hawc01\/hawcroot\/data\/hawc\/reconstructed\/quesadilla\/\$\{RUN\}/g" *.sh
```

the backslash should ignore special character replacement, but this returns the following error.

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "RUN\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "RUN\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

So it's searching for RUN\, which is not what I want... Any thoughts?  I would appreciate any help you can give.

Thanks!

Comment: You have problems building a shell command, so it would be nice to know which shell you are using!

Comment: Try with `'`s. Many shells change interpolation based on this, which the error message sounds like. Also, consider changing the `/` delimiter to avoid "leaning toothpicks". For instance, place the toothpicks straight: `s|INPUT=/foo/bar|AWESOME|` :D (Although this is not the only possible delimiter replacement and is a very poor choice if needing *alternations*.)

Comment: I am in Bash, and thanks!

Comment: my first attempt used ' as a delimiter and failed.  so i replaced " with ' and it became interactive (waiting for additional commands, i mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the pattern to be `...\$\{RUN\}...`, but that's not what you're passing:

```
$ echo "...\$\{RUN\}..."
...$\{RUN\}...
```

You either need do more escaping, or switch to single quotes.

```
$ echo '...\$\{RUN\}...'
...\$\{RUN\}...
```

All together:

```
perl -i -wpe'
    s{INPUT=/data/scratch02/mpgussert/HAWC-30/\$\{RUN\}_reco}
     {INPUT=/data/hawc01/hawcroot/data/hawc/reconstructed/quesadilla/\${RUN}}g
' *.sh
```